# SQL - query from a SQL query - how to read from unknown coumns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query for characters who go to forest `n` number of times:

```
select name, count(forest_entry) from characters
group by name
```

This results in:

```
name      |  count(forest_entry)
==========|==============
Gandalf   |  3
Samwise   |  2
Hobbit    |  3
Ork       |  2
Frodo     |  2
Galadriel |  1
```

Now I **want to reverse count number of times** to characters. For example, 3 people went to forest 2 times. 1 person went to forest 1 time (Galadriel). 2 people went to forest 3 times. 
Problem is that I don't have a column name to read from the first query.

How can I achieve this result:

```
number of times |  number of
went to forest  |  characters
================|==============
  3             |  2
  1             |  1
  2             |  3
```

Comment: On a sidenote: `characters` is a bad name for such a table, because it suggests that it contains one record per character, which is not the case. You should change it. But actually you should have an *additional*  table for the characters, so each record in your action/events/whatever table references a character in a character table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the computed column an alias name to use it in the outer query

```
select times, count(*) people
from
(
    select name, count(forest_entry) times
    from characters
    group by name
) tmp
group by times
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a sub query to first return the count of entries per character, then group by the count of entries and do another count on this:

```
DECLARE @forestentries TABLE (name varchar(50), entered bit)

INSERT INTO @forestentries VALUES ('Gandalf',1)
INSERT INTO @forestentries VALUES ('Gandalf',1)
INSERT INTO @forestentries VALUES ('Gandalf',1)
INSERT INTO @forestentries VALUES ('Samwise',1)
INSERT INTO @forestentries VALUES ('Samwise',1)

SELECT EntryCount, COUNT(*) [number of characters] FROM (
    SELECT Name, COUNT(entered) as EntryCount from @forestentries group by Name ) a
GROUP BY EntryCount
```

Comment: It is MySQL, not SQL Server.